# How do I access these id's with javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have website with a javaScript function that should scroll to section on page when user clicks a navigation item. This script worked before I made changes to my nav menu. I can not figure out how to reference the ID's in the javaScript correctly.

Here is HTML nav menu:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Data Detective</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a id="home" href="#homeSect">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a id="about" href="#aboutSect">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a id="portfolio" href="#portfolioSect">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                <li><a id="contact" href="#contactSect">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setBindings();
});


//Allow screen to Scroll to selected section
function setBindings() {
    $("nav ul li a").click(function (tip) {
        tip.preventDefault();
        var sectionID = "#" + tip.currentTarget.id + "Sect";
        alert('button id ' + sectionID);

        $("html body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(sectionID).offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

Comment: it should be .nav  instead of nav

Comment: I believe `$("nav ul li a")` should be `$(".nav ul li a")` or `$("ul.nav li a")`

Comment: Note that `var sectionID = "#" + tip.currentTarget.id + "Sect";` could just be `var sectionID = this.getAttribute("href");`

Comment: I have implemented these changes but the page still jumps to section it does not smooth scroll. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.navbar` class.
Please change:

```
 $("nav ul li a").click(function (tip) {
```

TO

```
$(".navbar ul li a").click(function (tip) {
```

Further more, I recommend you to use `var sectionID = $(this).attr('href');` instead `var sectionID =  "#" + tip.currentTarget.id + "Sect";` because it's more simply.

Comment: I have implemented these changes but the page still jumps to section it does not smooth scroll. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Your jQuery selector:

```
$("nav ul li a")
```

will search for the element `<nav>` (which doesn't exist).

Instead, you can use the selector:

```
$(".nav a")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do a more useful global function I guess. I would check for any href with an anchor reference, check if there is a div with that id, and then scroll to that one.

That way you're not limited to the menu but can use the same code everywhere. Also I made the event caputurer the top level document, so you can insert and remove elements at hearts content and it will always work without having to be rebound.

```js
$(document).on('click','a[href^="#"]',function(e) {
    var target = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');
    var $target = $(target);
  
    if($target.length > 0) {
      $("html body").animate({       
            scrollTop: $target.offset().top
      }, 1000);
     }
});
```

```css
div.sect {
   margin:50px;
  height:400px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a id="blah" href="www.google.nl">Excluded</a></li>
<li><a id="home" href="#homeSect">HOME</a></li>
<li><a id="about" href="#aboutSect">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a id="portfolio" href="#portfolioSect">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
<li><a id="contact" href="#contactSect">CONTACT</a></li>
<li><a id="blah" href="www.google.nl">Excluded</a></li>

<div class="sect" id="portfolioSect">
  portfolioSect
</div>

<div class="sect" id="homeSect">
  homeSect
</div>
<div class="sect" id="aboutSect">
  aboutSect
</div>
<div class="sect" id="contactSect">
  contactSect
</div>
```